# IIS 7.5 URL Rewrite not working? help please

Tags: url, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to get a URL rewrite so it takes a URL for e.g my.site.com and rewrites it to "Http://localhost:8080". I keep getting default homepage instead of it being redirected. I have configured the rewrite as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="mysite">
                <match url="(my.+)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8080" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am at a loss, is there something I am doing wrong ???

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you want to achieve and why, but because localhost is involved, it seems you do not want to *rewrite* but maybe perform a http *redirect*. *Rewriting* means that your request URL is sort of changed into another one, like index_foo.htm could be rewritten to index.aspx?what=foo.

But you want to change the domains, so you need to *redirect*. Try:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://localhost:8080" childOnly="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

This will keep whatever local page you have called, i. e. my.site.com/foo.htm will be redirected to localhost:8080/foo.htm.

Because this looks like a temporary thing for development purposes, you can add

```
 httpResponseStatus="Temporary"
```

to httpRedirect (may be important in order not to lose search engine rankings).

Comment: Hi Olaf, thanks for the reply, we are implementing a website with public access which uses a java app. the app will run on tomcat, so as a compaby security requirement we cannot have tomcat public facing. So we want to have all public requests come into IIS 7.5 and then get tham redirected to tomcat. So redirect all my.site.com request including parameters to http:localhost:8080 which will be the tomcat application (Port 8080 is nominal).

Comment: Then redirection will not work (a browser that gets localhost will try to access the computer it runs on). I doubt rewriting will work, at least not out of the box (the output of Tomcat would have to be routed through IIS and then to the browser). I don't know any tool that supports that, but you could write your own. The browser input would have to be forwarded internally to Tomcat and the result read and sent back to the browser.